# Simple method to distribute binary application to Linux/Debian users

Tags: linux, debian, installation, distribution

I need to distribute a small binary application to a limited number (around 20) of known users.

The installation process needs to be as **simple & user friendly** as possible. Ideally it is a single entry on the command line which downloads the binary & installs it.

Also important:

- Binary is a single file, no external dependencies.
- Binary needs to hook itself into the startup process via init.d.
- Target distro is the same for all users (Debian).

I am thinking along the line, to provide a single command to the users, i.e. something like this:

```
To install the app, please run this from the command line:
wget https://myapp.com/binary.tgz; tar xvfz binary.tgz; sudo install.sh
```

Are there more appropiate / simpler solutions I should be aware of?

*(Of course `sudo somethingFromTheInternet` is a security issue for a "real" distribution. However all my users are well known (+know me), and the number of users is very limited (around 20). So I am willing to trade ease of installation for security in this case)*

Comment: maybe you can provide a single script for users with all needed steps/commands.

Comment: Yes but then they need to download the script first. I thought of something like "Just copy&paste this to your command line"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are the users *ON* your network? Do you control the servers/workstations that the users will be using?

The right choice for your distro would be to package it ([deb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29) for packaging, [apt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) for distribution). That allow you to wrap some logic around the installation - executable permissions, sanity checks, init scripts, maybe even an opportunity to uninstall.

Comment: +1 for making a .deb. That's what they're for. Automatic dependencies, versionning, install scripts, post/pre install/remove scripts... that's what he needs.

Comment: No, I do not control the users workstations. Not on my network. The way I understand apt, the users would need to add a custom repository first, right?

Comment: You don't need to use apt. They can install a single package directly using dpkg. Additionally, look into Jordan Sissel's FPM. It's a dead simple package builder for deb and rpm.

Comment: That looks pretty good, thank you. So the command for the users would be wget https://myapp.com/myapp.deb; sudo dpgk -i myapp.deb, correct?

Comment: @henning77 That's right.